# Dynamic SQL vs Code Duplication

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Help!

I have a problem if I should use dynamic SQL or code duplication in my project or if my entire process is completely incorrect.

First - the example below is not correct, I have simplified it quite a lot to avoid too lengthy discussions about exactly what is going on.

Premise: I have a HUGE amount of people that have to be linked to an Address table that I have no control over. I link them to this address table either not at all (null) since I cannot find the correct address in our Address table *OR* I link them to the building (but not the apartment if it's an apartment building) cause it's apartments in the building and the address I got was without (or incorrect) apartment info.
Or, finally, I link them 100% to an apartment (completely correct match).

Since the Address table updates quite often with new information about addresses I have to try to re-match nulls and building matches to completely correct matches.
The matching logic is very extensive in several stored procedures.

Now... When I have incoming (new) People for my People table I first store them in IncomingPeople table to be able to handle all the matching in that table (smart ehe?) and then just "pour" these (already matched as good as I can today) People into the People table. The incoming table also holds people who should be added to the people table in the future with a Date variable so I don't add people who are not starting until later.

But! (and here it comes) when I need to see if I can re-match people who are null or building matched in the People database I cannot run the complex matching logic on the People table since it is so enormously huge and the matching logic is so complex.

My thought was to lift out the people from the People table to another table (here called RematchingPeople) who are not matched yet and then perform the matching logic on that table and then update the People table with the correct addressID if it has changed.

All of this works fine, no problem. But I EITHER need to duplicate the complex matching code to work in both IncomingPeople table AND RematchingPeople table (current method, but we change the matching logic from time to time and it's a hassle to update on both places) OR use dynamic SQL, but I'm a bit wary to do that - am I wrong? Is this one of the times where dynamic SQL is really awesome and I should just do it and be happy it exists?

```
People
(
    id int,
    name varchar(200),
    address varchar(200),
    postalcode int,
    city varchar(100),
    addressID bigint
)

IncomingPeople
(
    name varchar(200),
    address varchar(200),
    postalcode int,
    city varchar(100),
    startdate date
)

RematchingPeople
(
    id int,
    name varchar(200),
    address varchar(200),
    postalcode int,
    city varchar(100),
    addressID bigint,
    IsReMatched bit
)
```

Edited for readability

Comment: A few things here. First, this post is super long and extremely confusing. It would help if you could create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on the specific problem(s), which brings me to the problem itself. It sounds like you have a [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. You keep referencing *complex matching logic* without showing what this is, or why it's needed. We need sample data and expected output. The problem could be in your method of updating / matching, the workflow entirely, or who knows where else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it your IncomingPeople table is acting as a queue.
RematchingPeople is also like a queue to try and get a better match.

I would consider having a match_type and/or match_strength field in your people table and your RematchingPeople table.  This gives you a mechanism to identify how good a match you achieved at the time and therefore short-circuit any rematching activity so you only attempt stronger matches in future.

I would consider using sp_ExecuteSQL with your dynamic SQL as the case as described is for tables with very similar structures and unlikely to change.

In terms of clearing out your RematchingPeople queue tables you could make the update criteria for your people table where a match_type and/or score in the RematchingPeople table exceeds or matches that of the people table. The delete criteria would then become removing RematchingPeople whose match_type or score is less than or equal to that of your People table.

What I am not clear on is whether your IncomingPeople table can receive People that you may have loaded previously and whether a key for incoming people can be persisted through to People.  If you cannot get the same people being submitted as new ones then you may be able to deprecate your RematchingPeople table by adding match_type and/or score to IncomingPeople and simply pushing People back through the IncomingPeople queue.